# Get the mapping for the inserted Id and the existing Id in SQL Server while cloning

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to clone the data in a table using existing data with the insert and select statement like:

```
INSERT INTO Foundation.Products
OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO @insertedIdTable -- Need to get the existing Id also
SELECT Name, SupplierId, CategoryId
FROM Foundation.Products
WHERE Id = @existingProductId
```

Is there any way to map the inserted and the existing Id in the table. For which existing Id which new Id is created?

I know we can do this using the MERGE statement with Source and Destination as the same table

```
MERGE Foundation.Products
USING (SELECT * FROM Foundation.Products WHERE Id = @existingProductId) AS [Source]
ON (1=0) -- always insert
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Name, SupplierId, CategoryId)
    VALUES ([Source].Name, [Source].SupplierId,[Source].CategoryId)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, [Source].Id;
```

Comment: Why `IN` in the clause `Id IN (@existingProductId)`? and not simply `Id = @existingProductId`?

Comment: I don't really follow what you're asking here. If you want to `OUTPUT` a value from both the source table and the destination table, then yes, `MERGE` is what you are after; as that can reference columns not from the target table in the `OUTPUT` clause. Can you clarify your question here? Likely sample data and expected results/behaviour will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu I was using the code with multiple Ids that's why I used IN but to simplify the question I removed all that dynamic portion and you are right I should just use direct =  instead of IN (updating the question) and my question is just that, Can this thing be achieved using normal INSERT SELECT without MERGE. The answer can be a yes or no and answer with reason will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you want can't be done with insert - output. You'll have to use merge. Is there some reason why you don't want to use merge?